# Invalid Auth Token with Rails, Graphql, Apollo Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, authenticity-token, apollo-client

I am trying to get a basic Rails, Graphql, Apollo-Client setup working but having trouble with 422 errors 'invalid auth token' on the rails side.

Does my use of apollo look wrong?

It is a Rails 5 app with graphql gem and apollo client.

```
const csrfToken = document.getElementsByName('csrf-token')[0].content
const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    uri: '/graphql',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
    }
  }),
});
client.query({
query: gql`
    query Camillo2 {
      user {
        id
        email
        created_at
      }
    }
  `,
})
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Rails log:

```
Started POST "/graphql" for ::1 at 2017-03-10 08:51:58 -0800
Processing by GraphqlController#create as */*
Parameters: {"query"=>"query Camillo2 {\n  user {\n    id\n    email\n    created_at\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n", "operationName"=>"Camillo2", "graphql"=>{"query"=>"query Camillo2 {\n  user {\n    id\n    email\n    created_at\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n", "operationName"=>"Camillo2"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 8):

Since Apollo 2.0 and according to

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/Upgrade.md

Just do this way

```
const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').getAttribute('content');
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
        }
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Using apollo-boost, it's a little different.

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  },
  request: (operation) => {
    const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').getAttribute('content')
    operation.setContext({
      headers: { "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken }
    })
  },
})
```

Comment: just remember to add  <%= csrf_meta_tags %> to the layout!

Answer (score 2):

this one works fine for me.

```ruby
const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').getAttribute('content');
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting with Apollo on Rails the other day, here's the configuration that worked for me:

```
var RailsNetworkInterface = apollo.createNetworkInterface('/graphql', {
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content"),
  }
});

var client = new apollo.ApolloClient({networkInterface: RailsNetworkInterface})

client.query({ query: gql`{ event(id: 7) { name } }`})
```

But, it seems like yours would work just as well!

Can you confirm that the proper token is being sent to the server? For example, if you open the network tab of Chrome devtools, then make a query, can you see the `X-CSRF-Token` in the "Request Headers" section?

Also, it's possible that Rails is updating the CSRF token in the DOM, but the NetworkInterface keeps the old, stale CSRF token. Can you confirm that the token in the "Request Headers" section matches the *current* value in the `<meta>` tag? (I was surprised that I didn't encounter this problem myself, using Turbolinks Classic.)

Comment: Thanks for your example and ideas. Strange but by switching my query to pass the url as the first arg (as per your example) no longer results in 422 error. Although Apollo tells me that that is deprecated and my syntax above with uri: "..." is the preferred!

Answer (score 1):

To clarify some of the above answers, since one of the users noted that passing in the uri as a first argument to createNetworkInterface works but logs a deprecation message in the console: you have to pass in options like "credentials" and "headers" in as properties of an options object like so:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: '/graphql',
  opts: {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
    },
  },
});
```

See the second example under Fetch in the docs: http://dev.apollodata.com/core/network.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (I'm using react_on_rails):

```
import { ApolloClient, createNetworkInterface } from 'react-apollo';
import ReactOnRails from 'react-on-rails';

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: '/graphql',
  opts: {
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  }
});
networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware(req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {
        "X-CSRF-Token": ReactOnRails.authenticityToken()
      }
    }
    next();
  }
}]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface
});

export default client
```

I was missing **opts: { credentials: 'same-origin' }** , resulting in the same error: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity

Answer (score 0):

Was running into a 422 error myself on the `/graphql` endpoint when firing Apollo query client side (React in my case).

There are 2 major things that could be happening.

1.) Make triple, quadruple, quintuple... sure that you have not made any typos. the Apollo client config can get quite terse, so just be super prudent about the token setup code you write.

```
// Get Token from Meta Tags on Application.html.erb

const getToken = () => document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

const token = getToken();

// MiddleWare Operationt that sets the CSRF token on requests to protect from forgery
const setTokenForOperation = async operation =>
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': token,
    },
  });

// Link With CSRF Token
const createLinkWithToken = () =>
  new ApolloLink(
    (operation, forward) =>
      new Observable(observer => {
        let handle;
        Promise.resolve(operation)
          .then(setTokenForOperation)
          .then(() => {
            handle = forward(operation).subscribe({
              next: observer.next.bind(observer),
              error: observer.error.bind(observer),
              complete: observer.complete.bind(observer),
            });
          })
          .catch(observer.error.bind(observer));

        return () => {
          if (handle) handle.unsubscribe();
        };
      })
  );

... other apollo-link middleware stuff like error logging etc

// Tell Apollo client about the endpoint for making queries: (HTTP LINK) - this was default endpoint added by graphql install



const createHttpLink = () =>
  new HttpLink({
    uri: '/graphql',
    credentials: 'include',
  });

// and finally put it all together 

export const createClient = (cache, requestLink) =>
  new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([createErrorLink(), createLinkWithToken(), createHttpLink()]),
    cache,
  });
```

2.) Protect from Forgery Session fail on 3rd party authentication strategies (ie Devise + CanCan or w/e )

If your apollo middleware patterns are kosher, then it could be that your authentication strategy might be impeding the request.

for example I am using devise + cancan, which was also causing some seeming random 422s which was easily solved with some research (see this article https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/06/rails-5-default-protect-from-forgery-prepend-false.html)

long story short on this part, you may need to have application controller (especially if you are upgrading from a legacy version) load and authorize your current user/resource AFTER the protect from forgery setup (more deets on the article referenced)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :exception

... 
before_action .. whatever else you have going on hereafter
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers