# Rails CSRF protection with Single Page Application (react, angular, ember)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, csrf, csrf-protection

Ok. I officially lost my mind with this problem.

Let's take a default Rails application (`5`, but I tried also with a `4` default app).

I'm trying to use a simple javascript code to send an ajax POST request to one controller action.

In my `ApplicationController` I have this code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  after_action :set_csrf_cookie

  protected

    def set_csrf_cookie
      cookies["X-CSRF-Token"] = form_authenticity_token
    end

end
```

which sets a cookie `"X-CSRF-Token"` with the value of `form_authenticity_token`.

After that I can read this cookie in my SPA (Single Page Application) using this code:

```
<script>
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) === " ") c = c.substring(1, c.length);
      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
  }

// var token = document.getElementsByName('csrf-token')[0].content; // this works!
const token = readCookie("X-CSRF-Token"); // this doesn't work!

fetch('/api/v1', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {""},
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-Token': token
  },
  credentials: 'include'
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
});
</script>
```

When I use this line:

```
var token = document.getElementsByName('csrf-token')[0].content;
```

it works because it reads what Rails insert in html page with:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="VXaKlO+/Gr/8pGhr5y0bThQ5L/0IDiznMR/9SpaoI6vOoF9KtmB5/9ka+Hz+zjyssNRi/Em/Ye27C+E5pl3odg==">
```

So the content of "csrf-token" works and my Rails application can validate CSRF.

This is the code from Rails source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.0/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb

**When instead I use this line:**

```
const token = readCookie("X-CSRF-Token");
```

**it doesn't work and I get this error:**

```
Started POST "/api/v1" for 172.18.0.1 at 2018-05-01 18:52:56 +0000
Processing by MyController#action as */*
  Parameters: {"body"=>{}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

Also if I use another page with another server (npm http-server or Microsoft IIS or others) with the same script the problem is the same.

If I copy the content of "csrf-token" from Rails html page and use this line in my Javascript script:

```
const token = "VXaKlO+/Gr/8pGhr5y0bThQ5L/0IDiznMR/9SpaoI6vOoF9KtmB5/9ka+Hz+zjyssNRi/Em/Ye27C+E5pl3odg==";
```

**it WORKS!**

So my question is: **WHY?**

---

What I have read (nut nothing!):

- https://github.com/equivalent/scrapbook2/blob/master/archive/blogs/2017-10-12-csrf-protection-on-single-page-app-api.md
- [Invalid Auth Token with Rails, Graphql, Apollo Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723989/invalid-auth-token-with-rails-graphql-apollo-client)
- https://www.bhalash.com/archives/13544808782
- [Rails CSRF Protection + Angular.js: protect_from_forgery makes me to log out on POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734243/rails-csrf-protection-angular-js-protect-from-forgery-makes-me-to-log-out-on)
- https://technpol.wordpress.com/2014/04/17/rails4-angularjs-csrf-and-devise/
- [Work with authenticity token? Or disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573024/work-with-authenticity-token-or-disable-it)
- [Rails API design without disabling CSRF protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600347/rails-api-design-without-disabling-csrf-protection)

Comment: You could simplify your readCookie function with this:

`document.cookie.match("X-CSRF-Token=([^;]+)")[1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the header Rails expects is `X_CSRF_TOKEN` (note the underscores). I don't see a problem with the rest of the code you've shared - except maybe that the token from the cookie must be URI decoded (`decodeURIComponent`), so check this as well if you still get the warning.

Comment: Are you sure about underscores in `X_CSRF_TOKEN`?

Comment: It shouldn't matter too much as Rails most probably treats them the same - it's how I use it though so just to be on the safe side. Posting only when I know certainly it works :)

Comment: I think it is here in code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L287 and I see hyphens... right?

Comment: There is a lot going on under the hood, check https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/834be61e61a1ed55f056cdff12ffe4cdcaa7ca65/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L47 as well - the headers in the request environment are all underscore, however they have already been processed.. I think it's safe to assume that 1. Using the header with hyphens is the preferred way and 2. Rails/rack seems to treat hyphens and underscores equally

Answer (score 6):

Tnx, I got your code working. I only needed to add `decodeURIComponent()`

```
const token = decodeURIComponent(readCookie("X-CSRF-Token"));
```

I used this approach for a Progressive Web App with cached html. The default rails meta tag (`<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`) doesn't work with cached html.

This blog post also gives some other alternatives: https://www.fastly.com/blog/caching-uncacheable-csrf-security

Comment: Could you give some more details about how you reproduced this problem with cached html? I'm having the same issue (I believe) with my SPA. I'm setting the X-CSRF-Token in a header, but have recently received a huge spike of InvalidAuthenticityToken exceptions, I believe because some browser is caching HTML when the browser closes (and my cookie expires).

Answer (score 1):

are you checked`readCookie("X-CSRF-Token")` value?
the value probably is different when storing to cookie, probably the value escaped